# Selecting specific lists in a file

Tags: python

I've been working with a Python dictionary to replace md5 values with COG/NOG identifiers. This is what I have done so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

fil = sys.argv[1]

# load md5 -> COG into dictionary

with open(fil) as fin: 
    rows = ( line.strip().split('\t') for line in fin )
    d = { row[0]:row[1] for row in rows }

# open blast output, replace md5 with COG by looking up md5 in the dictionary

    blasted = open(sys.argv[2])
    for line in blasted:
            linearr = line.split()
            if linearr[2] > '90.00':
                    line.split()
                    needed = linearr[0:2]
                    md5 = linearr[1]                                
                    ret = []
                    for md5 in needed:
                            ret.append(d.get(md5,md5))
                            "".join(ret)
                            print ret
```

This has brought me to this output, lists of various size and content...

```
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', 'f3e68ef307f962ba6b836a94ff0e2216']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', 'COG0860']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', '05e94199eef6fbaf225618f9deaf847c']
```

So the single item lists need to be tossed as well as the lists that retain the md5 value. What I need is to select for only the lists that have the COG/NOG second element, as in the 4th list above.

I can't select for the second item of the lists to filter these results because not all lists have a second item. Can anyone suggest a method for this?

UPDATE:
I was able to remove the lists with only one item. Now my lists look like this...

```
['fig|357276.26.peg.4485', 'NOG73961']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4485', '19c060b530e8fa9598de068387bc3225']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', '8daa25fe83eb1a204c51861cb77945f5']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', '5c253078a0a6c51eca320dfd92991a70']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', '8707bd7fa7489ff69233ce735c1c6cbf']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', 'f3e68ef307f962ba6b836a94ff0e2216']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', 'COG0860']
['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', '05e94199eef6fbaf225618f9deaf847c']
```

Now I need to select for only the lists containing a second item starting with NOG or COG...any advice?

Comment: `[l for l in lst if len(l) > 1 and len(l[1]) == 7]` -- instead of len of l[1] you can check for len < 10 or l[1].startswith("COG") or whatever is a more appropriate for your case. Just some filtering value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say your have a list of lists like `values = [ [1], [1,2], [3,4] ]`

First you remove all items with the `filter` function:

```
values1 = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1, values)
```

Now you need to filter based on the COG/NOG. As there are only lists with 2 elements now, we can directly choose the second element :

```
filter(lambda x: "NOG" in x[1] of "COG" in x[1], values1)
```

TO reduce the whole thing down, we can merge both:

```
def check_cog_nog(x):
    if len(x) > 1:
        y = x[1].lower()
        if "nog" in y or "cog" in y:
            return True
    return False

filter(check_cog_nog, values)
```

Comment: I actually just tried "if len(ret) > 1:" to get to the update posted in the original post

Comment: Got it figured out using your method! Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Just check that the list is long enough using len() before you attempt to access the second element.

[Edit:  just like the first comment above, which posted after I started this answer.  (I don't have enough reputation to comment myself.)]

[Edit 2:  Here are a couple of notes about your code. Unless you are sure about the source of the data, you might want to consider doing some checks to make sure each line is valid for what you need.]

```
blasted = open(sys.argv[2])
for line in blasted:
        linearr = line.split()
        if linearr[2] > '90.00':  # <-- this will blow up if not enough elements
                line.split()      # <--- this doesn't do anything
                needed = linearr[0:2]  # <- this could get 0-3 elements
                md5 = linearr[1]  # <-- This will blow up if not enough elements
                ret = []
                for md5 in needed:
                        ret.append(d.get(md5,md5))
                        "".join(ret)
                        print ret
```

Answer (score 0):

If your list is stored in the `variable` `ret` then you can use this list comprehension to achieve what you need:

```
new_ret = [i for i in ret if len(i) > 1 and (i[1].startswith('COG') or i[1].startswith('NOG'))]
print (new_ret)
```

The output:

```
[['fig|357276.26.peg.4486', 'COG0860']]
```

If `ret` has elements where `i[1]` starts with `NOD`, `new_ret` will contain those elements as well.